# Spring Batch - Is it possible to to be fault tolerant in different ways for different exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

So for example I have 3 levels of exceptions, minor, regular, critical. In an ideal world I would like to essentially have 3 listeners on the app for these exceptions and if 10 minors occur or 5 regular or 1 critical I stop the application and send a notification to the interested parties. Is this possible or is there a way in which I could develop this behavior?

Comment: Are you writing tasklets? Or processors? Because there are listeners for the processor classes which could track exception counts in the execution context

Comment: I am writing processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the Spring Batch `SkipPolicy` mechanism.

Spring Batch provides a few `SkipPolicy` implementations to manage fault tolerance: `AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy`, `CompositeSkipPolicy`, `ExceptionClassifierSkipPolicy`, `LimitCheckingItemSkipPolicy` and `NeverSkipItemSkipPolicy`.

If no one fits your need, it is probably easy to make your own `SkipPolicy` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you could create a database table that could log errors and each entry can be linked with a session id assuming this might be a web application. Have a separate job run every 5 minutes that could poll the database table for this criteria to be met. If this was android platform you could use RX Java and send a push notification using Google Firebase.